# Label showing extra decimal places

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling

Based on the map below how can I set the labels to show values with only `2` decimal places?
As you can see the field (float) is already set to `2` decimal points but for some reason, label values have more than `2` decimal places. I tried again after restarting `ArcGIS Pro 3.03` but, the issue persists.

How can I fix this?
Should I create a new field and convert the values to `text` and then use this field for labeling?

Map:

[image]

Column:

[image]

Comment: Have you read [How To: Round off numbers to a given number of decimal places in an attribute table and label in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000025170)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS Pro open the Labeling Properties.  There are several ways to round numbers.  You would want to ensure that you replace the expressions with the name of your data.  Here I am rounding a longitude with Arcade but you could look up how to round with Python, VB, or Javascript.

```
Round($feature.Longitude, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, cheers.